# Import Multiple Excel Files into Master Excel File including its Filename

Tags: excel, vba, filenames

Currently I have multiple Excel Files in a folder. But the data in each excel files do not have its file name. So, by using Macros, how can I import Excel files including its file name once the each excel file is imported (into Master Excel and in the same sheet)? Somebody can help me?

Comment: When asking a question, it's generally expected you show an example of what you've tried so far and where you got hung up so the community can properly assist. I'm going to assume you're using a FileSystemObject with this files, in which case you could try the `.path` propery. Edit your question with more detail and code examples.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.